# Emacs tab width XML

Tags: xml, emacs

I am editing an XML file in emacs which has a tab width of 4, so I would like to change emacs' tab width the 4 also. I don't want to edit my `.emacs` as this is the only time I want to change tab widths (I won't need it again). How do I do this?

**Edit:** As a way of clarification here is a screenshot of how I might achieve this in Sublime Text 2 (I'm not trying to start a editor war; I'd rather like to be able to do something like this in emacs)

[image]

Comment: `M-x eval-expression RET your-code RET`  Some major modes have their own way of setting tab widths.  For a major mode that has nothing special already programmed for tabs, you might want to try something like:  `M-x eval-expression RET (progn (setq indent-tabs-mode t) (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 4 200 4)) (setq tab-width 4) (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)) RET`  I'm not familiar enough with xml-mode to know whether it has something special beyond the regular tab setting stuff . . . you may need to open the source code and take a peek.

Comment: Also, **eval-expression** is normally bound to **M-:**, so you can hit that and then enter your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

M-x customize-variable
return
Then input "tab-width", and you could find the configuration of tab-width, set the value and apply it.

[image]

Comment: The trouble with this is after saving the change and switching back to my xml buffer the behaviour is the same. Also, this writes to my init.el, but I only need the change for the buffer I'm using.

Comment: You were nearly right! The variable I was after is `nxml-child-indent`